# Adding a strategy to a Zend\Form\Element\Collection

Tags: zend-framework2

Is there a way to add a Hydration strategy to a `Zend\Form\Element\Collection` element? I tried it the normal way:

```
$hydrator = new ClassMethods();
$hydrator->addStrategy('language', new LanguageStrategy($em));
$hydrator->addStrategy('items', new UnitItemsStrategy($em));
$this->setHydrator($hydrator);
```

With the element:

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
    'name' => 'items',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Items',
        'count' => 1,
        'should_create_template' => true,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'target_element' => array(
            'type' => 'Application\Form\UnitItemFieldset',
        ),
    ),
));
```

But the hydrator strategy just never gets called. When I just remap it to another element like `text` it gets called. So it seems to have to do with the element being a `Zend\Form\Element\Collection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, they can be just added to collections as to any other element. In my case there have been several mistakes in using collections correctly:

- did not call `$form->prepare()` in the view script
- did not use `ClassMethods` hydrator for a while (due to debugging), but I do not know why this should be a problem (yet it was, but probably I am missing something else)

Another possible problem I just found out:

- your method used by `ClassMethods` (e.g. `setItems` in my case) is not callable, then ZF will not call the hydrator strategy either